# PHP - Woocommerce 3.2 Add variable shipping insurance with multiple "else if " conditions

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

This is my first post here, I am very new to PHP so bare with me.

I need to add USPS's variable shipping rates for priority mail based on cart total. I have tried plugins but none of them work right with the USPS shipping plugin client insists on using and I have maxed budget for buying any other plugins.

I have created a child theme and added a new functions.php. That is the correct way of adding update-proof php correct?

I found a php function on Git that adds a rate based on an over/under cart amount but I need to add more else if conditions for 7 variable cart totals. Below is my best attempt at adding the conditions I need with my very limited knowledge of php. Can someone please help me get this code working? What am I missing to allow for multiple else if conditions?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','woocommerce_custom_surcharge' );
```

function woocommerce_custom_surcharge() {
  global $woocommerce;

```
if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
    return;

$chosen_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
$chosen_shipping = $chosen_methods[0];

if ( strpos($chosen_shipping, 'USPS_Simple_Shipping_Method' ) !== false ) {
    // this compare needed since if the string is found at beg of target, it returns '0', which is a false value

    $insurance_fee = 0;
    if ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total  <= 50 ) {
        $insurance_fee = 0;
        return;
    } else {
        if ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total  > 50  ) { 
            $insurance_fee = 2.05; 
            return; 
    } else {
         if ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total  > 100  ) { 
            $insurance_fee = 2.45; 
            return; 
    } else {
         if ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total  > 200  ) { 
            $insurance_fee = 4.60; 
            return;
    } else {
         if ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total  > 300  ) { 
            $insurance_fee = 5.50; 
            return;
    } else {
         if ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total  > 400  ) { 
            $insurance_fee = 6.40; 
            return;
    } else {
         if ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total  > 500  ) { 
            $insurance_fee = 7.30; 
            return;
    }

    $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Insurance', $insurance_fee, true, '' );
}
return;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that stumbles on this and wants to implement it I have posted the code as a gist where I keep it updated. I recently added an if statement to turn shipping insurance off if local pick up is selected

https://gist.github.com/Zach-Toth/95041d32b072109fa8fd99c60eff1c5a

Answer (score 0):

So, you are returning empty in every if statement, the function will never get to the:

```
$woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Insurance', $insurance_fee, true, '' );
```

Take a look at the changes I've made below, I also think you should add a fallback if the shipping method is not USPS.

```
function woocommerce_custom_surcharge() { 
      global $woocommerce;

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    //General Fall back for shipping and cart totals <= 50
    $insurance_fee = 0;
    $chosen_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
    $chosen_shipping = $chosen_methods[0];

    if ( strpos($chosen_shipping, 'USPS_Simple_Shipping_Method' ) !== false ) {

        if ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total  > 500  ) { 
                $insurance_fee = 7.30; 
        } else if ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total  > 400  ) { 
                $insurance_fee = 6.40; 
        } else if ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total  > 300  ) { 
                $insurance_fee = 5.50; 
        } else if ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total  > 200  ) { 
                $insurance_fee = 4.60; 
        } else if ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total  > 100  ) { 
                $insurance_fee = 2.45; 
        } else if ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total  > 50  ) { 
                $insurance_fee = 2.05; 
        }
    }

    //The fallback $insurance_fee value of 0 will be used if none of the conditions are met
    $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Insurance', $insurance_fee, true, '' );
}
```

Comment: THANKS! I had to remove the strpos compare to get it to work. Hopefully that doesnt cause any issues. But now I am only returning the first if condition even when the else if conditions are met. Hmmm

Comment: I will give it a try.

Comment: It works just fine, on my side. Can you print $chosen_shipping with ```var_dump($chosen_shipping)```?

Comment: I just needed to reverse the order of the statements. First if statement was met so others werent checked. Could have also added <= to every statement

Comment: Understood! I change the answer to match your needs, please accept it as the final answer.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I had the statements in the wrong order, the first if statement was satisfied so none of the others were checked. Reversed them and voila! I also could have added a <= to each statement

```
//General Fall back for shipping and cart totals <= 50
$insurance_fee = 0;
$chosen_methods = WC()->session->get( 'USPS_Simple' );
$chosen_shipping = $chosen_methods[0]; {

    if ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total  > 500  ) { 
            $insurance_fee = 7.30; 
    } else if ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total  > 400  ) { 
            $insurance_fee = 6.40; 
    } else if ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total  > 300  ) { 
            $insurance_fee = 5.50; 
    } else if ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total  > 200  ) { 
            $insurance_fee = 4.60; 
    } else if ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total  > 100  ) { 
            $insurance_fee = 2.45; 
    } else if ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total  >= 50  ) { 
            $insurance_fee = 2.05; 
    }
}

//The fallback $insurance_fee value of 0 will be used if none of the conditions are met
$woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Shipping Insurance', $insurance_fee, true, '' );
```

}